# Unpredictable pseudo-RNG

Tags: c++, random, rsa

I'm working on a cryptography project in C++ for school, and I'm going to need a way to generate random numbers that can't be regenerated by someone else (who "guessed" the seed).
To be precise, I'd need either a pure random generator, or a way to get 100% "secure" seed. I've already done some research and thinking, and I've found two ways I *could* do it, the first way of doing it would be initialising the seed with the current time, but this leaves me to worry that the "hacker" might find out the moment of the generation of the key, and then they'll have the seed, and therefore will be able to predict the next generated numbers. The second way of doing it I found was to ask the user for a seed.
Now, what if I don't want the user to generate the key ? And are my worries about the time-based seed founded or are they just pure paranoia ? Is there a chance anyone could get the execution moment for the code ? Or are there maybe other ways of doing it that I've missed ?
Sidenote: I'm using the `random_default_engine` from `<random>`

Comment: You can ask the user to type something, then use something from that as your seed. Also, check `::std::random_device`.

Comment: Using the system time is a weak seed because an attacker who knows approximately when the message was encrypted can easily brute-force an attack using every timestamp in a window around that period -- say, within half an hour of when they think it happened. The problem of generating entropy for a pseudo-RNG is a very active field of study; there ought to be many articles and research papers describing the pros and cons of different methods you've considered.

Comment: You don't know, but your question involves one of the biggest dilemas of the universe! Does exist anything that is really random??! (I don't think so, but there are people that think YES and they have good arguments). I think this article is of your interest: http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number

Comment: @user1095108 I've already thought of doing that, and I actually think that's the best answer, especially thanks to the other answer, which said it *is* possible to hack it easily

Comment: @qwrrty thanks, I'll just ask the user for a seed (or I'll add a way of generating a seed from time, but I'll tell the user that it's not safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user1095108 had the right idea, but the comment probably was too short.

Ask the user to type something at random. Each character is about 1 bit of randomness. Users are pretty bad at choosing random characters. Yet, you'll need about 40-50 bits.

However, users are also pretty bad at typing at an exact rhythm. The **timing** of each keystroke adds an extra few bits of randomness, depending on how accurately your OS can report that. With millisecond resolution, 10 keystrokes should be enough.

Comment: Interesting. How do I time the keystrokes though ? Also random_device seems to fit my needs, but I'm pretty sure it also has disadvantages (for example it won't work on a system without a way of getting that random bit of information needed)

Comment: Not in portable C++, basically. Standard input is line oriented.

Comment: So I'll have to code a different function for each OS I'll want the program to work on. Is there maybe any other way of generating something from user input ? Also, I just checked, my computer doesn't support true RNG, so I'll have to code it that way.

Comment: @Rudy132: Qt is a portable library which does support individual key-down events. Might be a bit overkill, but it also gets you a nice GUI.

Comment: Yeah I know about Qt, but since this is a school project I'd prefer to avoid having external libraries in it :/